# How to utilize globalization in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, globalization

I have created 3 resx files in `App_GlobalResources` folder in `asp.net` project in order to make a multilingual website, as you know it's sort of `key-value` set, everything seems good else cases in which I want to use values in JavaScript.

If I use inline JavaScript in aspx file it can be done using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26526472/4344976) way or

```
alert('<%= GetGlobalResourceObject([ResourceClassName],[ResourceKey]) %>');
```

Or

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:[ResourceClassName], [ResourceKey] %>"/>
```

but how should I achieve that in JavaScript files in which I am not able to use server side code?

Comment: I add the string in an hiddenfield and then use it in my js.

Comment: What if there are hundreds of values just like a .resx file?

Comment: This post might help you? https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Apr/02/A-Localization-Handler-to-serve-ASPNET-Resources-to-JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a structure similar to what we use in `ASP.Net` and I apply JavaScript object like what `CKEditor` uses in multilingual feature.

Imagine you have these files:

```
Culture.js
Main.js
Default.aspx
```

**Culture.js**

Place all words and phrases related to translations like this:

```
  if (typeof resource == "undefined") {
    resource = {}// = new Object();
    resource.lang = {};
  }

    //English language, United States culture
    resource.lang['en-US'] = {
        "lable": {
            "clickHere": "Click here",
            "enterYourName": "Enter your name"
        },
        "message": {
            "deleteConfimation": "Are You sure you want to delete?",
            "accessIsDenied": "Access is denied"
        }
    }

    //Farsi language, Iran culture 
    resource.lang['fa-IR'] = {
        "lable": {
            "clickHere": "اینجا کلیک کنید",
            "enterYourName": "نام خود را وارد کنید"
        },
        "message": {
            "deleteConfimation": "آیا از حذف این مورد اطمینان دارید؟",
            "accessIsDenied": "دسترسی مقدور نیست"
        }
    }
```

You can add as much as languages and cultures you need, just use `language-culture` combination in `resourse.lang['language-culture']` to make them distinguishable, finally define a function just like what you use in ASP.Net named `getGlobalResourceObject()`

```
 var getGlobalResourceObject = function (resourceClassName, resourceKey)
{
    return resourse.lang[window.lang][resourceClassName][resourceKey];
}
```

**Main.js**

```
window.lang = "en-US";//Or "fa-IR"
alert(getGlobalResourceObject("message", "deleteConfimation"));
```

It will alert a message saying "Are You sure you want to delete?" if `window.lang` equals to `en-US`.
(I prefer to set current culture in `window.lang`).

**Default.aspx**

In `Default.aspx` or `MasterPage` if you have any, load `Culture.js` just before `Main.js`, something like this:

```
<script src="Culture.js"></script>
<script src="Main.js"></script>
```